# How can I get rid of bezier handles when moving an object?

Tags: adobe-after-effects, bezier-curve

I am trying to move an object in straight lines as in the image below but the Bezier handles won't make this possible. How can I get rid of them and move my shape in straight lines with no curves whatsoever? Is there a way that they (bezier handles) can be turned off completely also?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the bezier path created by position keyframes.

Something like this:

[image]

Select the keyframes and <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> any of the points with the Pen Tool and you'll get this:

[image]

You can <kbd>alt</kbd> + drag the points/handles to control the bezier just as you can in Illustrator, so you can—for example—do something like this:

[image]

You can also right click the keyframes and select *Keyframe Interpolation* for a few more options. *Spacial Interpolation* is what controls the positional movement ("Linear" will give you no curve), but you can also change the *Temporal Interpolation*, which controls the timing:

[image]